# Indy SMTP sending email with GMail suddenly stopped working

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe7

Using: Delphi XE7, latest daily build of Indy 10.

This code was working 2 months earlier. Now I recompiled my app, and its not working anymore, with the same account details. The exception message is 'Disconnected'.

The SMTP port used is 587.

Code follows:

```
  FIdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create;
  FIdSSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  FIdMessage := TIdMessage.Create;
  FIdAttachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts);

  if (FEmailServer.SMTPUseSSL) then
  begin
    FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    // FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    FIdSMTP.IOHandler := FIdSSLIOHandler;
    FIdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    // FIdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
  end;

  FIdSMTP.Host := FEmailServer.SMTPHost; //smtp.gmail.com
  FIdSMTP.Port := FEmailServer.SMTPPort; //587
  FIdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
  FIdSMTP.Username := FEmailServer.SMTPUserName;
  FIdSMTP.Password := FEmailServer.SMTPPassword;

  FIdMessage.Recipients[0].Address := mailmessage.RecipientEmailAddr;
  FIdMessage.From.Name := mailmessage.SenderName;
  FIdMessage.Subject := mailmessage.EmailSubject;
  FIdMessage.Body.Text := mailmessage.EmailMessage;

  FIdAttachment.LoadFromFile(mailmessage.AttachmentFile);
  FIdAttachment.FileName := ExtractFileName(mailmessage.AttachmentFile);

  try
    if (not FIdSMTP.Connected) then
      FIdSMTP.Connect;

    FIdSMTP.Send(FIdMessage);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
```

Do you see anything obvious that could be causing it to not send the email?

Comment: Are you sending bulk email? If so, Google may have blocked you.

Comment: `FIdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault` - try using `satSASL` instead and populate the `TIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms` collection with SASL components (CRAM-MD5, CRAM-SHA1, etc). Also, in `TIdAttachmentFile.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts)`, you are not specifying a filename to attach, pass `mailmessage.AttachmentFile` to the constructor instead of using `LoadFromFile()`. And `FIdMessage.Recipients[0]` will fail with a bounds error since you have not added any items to the `Recipients` collection, use `Recipients.EmailAddresses := ...` instead of `Recipients[0].Address := ...`.

Comment: @Remy: Thank you, It worked!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, Remy! Beautiful tip! This code now works:

```
  FIdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create;
  FIdSSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  FIdMessage := TIdMessage.Create;
  FIdAttachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts);


  FIdSASLCRAMSHA1 := TIdSASLCRAMSHA1.Create;
  FIdSASLCRAMMD5 := TIdSASLCRAMMD5.Create;
  FIdSASLDigest := TIdSASLDigest.Create;
  FIdSASLSKey := TIdSASLSKey.Create;
  FIdSASLOTP := TIdSASLOTP.Create;
  FIdSASLAnonymous := TIdSASLAnonymous.Create;
  FIdSASLExternal := TIdSASLExternal.Create;
  FIdSASLLogin := TIdSASLLogin.Create;
  FIdSASLPlain := TIdSASLPlain.Create;

  if (FEmailServer.SMTPUseSSL) then
  begin
    FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    // FIdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    FIdSMTP.IOHandler := FIdSSLIOHandler;
    FIdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    // FIdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
  end;

  FIdSMTP.Host := FEmailServer.SMTPHost; //smtp.gmail.com
  FIdSMTP.Port := FEmailServer.SMTPPort; //587
  FIdSMTP.AuthType := satSASL;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLCRAMSHA1;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLCRAMMD5;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLDigest;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLSKey;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLOTP;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLAnonymous;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLExternal;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLLogin;
  FIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := FIdSASLPlain;      
  FIdSMTP.Username := FEmailServer.SMTPUserName;
  FIdSMTP.Password := FEmailServer.SMTPPassword;

  FIdMessage.Recipients[0].Address := mailmessage.RecipientEmailAddr;
  FIdMessage.From.Name := mailmessage.SenderName;
  FIdMessage.Subject := mailmessage.EmailSubject;
  FIdMessage.Body.Text := mailmessage.EmailMessage;

  FIdAttachment.LoadFromFile(mailmessage.AttachmentFile);
  FIdAttachment.FileName := ExtractFileName(mailmessage.AttachmentFile);

  try
    if (not FIdSMTP.Connected) then
      FIdSMTP.Connect;

    FIdSMTP.Send(FIdMessage);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
```

Freeing up the objects:

```
  FIdAttachment.Free;
  FIdMessage.Free;
  FIdSSLIOHandler.Free;
  FIdSMTP.Free;

  FIdSASLCRAMSHA1.Free;
  FIdSASLCRAMMD5.Free;
  FIdSASLDigest.Free;
  FIdSASLSKey.Free;;
  FIdSASLOTP.Free;
  FIdSASLAnonymous.Free;
  FIdSASLExternal.Free;
  FIdSASLLogin.Free;
  FIdSASLPlain.Free;
```

..the USES list:

> uses Classes, SysUtils, Windows, IdSMTP, IdMessage, IdSSLOpenSSL,
>   IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdAttachmentFile, IdSASL,
>   IdSASLCollection, IdSASLAnonymous,   IdSASLDigest, IdSASLExternal,
>   IdSASLLogin, IdSASLOTP, IdSASLPlain, IdSASLSKey, IdSASLUserPass,
>   IdSASL_CRAM_MD5, IdSASL_CRAM_SHA1;

Comment: The `SASLMechanisms` collection tries the authorizations in the order they are specified, so you should add the entries in order from higher security to lower security, eg: CRAM-SHA1, CRAM-MD5, Digest, SKey, OTP, Anonymous, External, Login, Plain.